# High CPU usage on Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using Storage Emulator v 3.2 and I've just uploaded about 370.000 blobs totalling some 75GB. Now I'm experiencing constant CPU usage of between 35-40% by the emulator process just by doing nothing (i.e. not actively using the emulator).

Does anyone know what the emulator is doing "when it's not doing anything"? Is it doing some sort of indexing or anything? Would the constant CPU usage have something to do with the large number of files (if 370K files is considered large anyway) or large amount of storage used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator is not built for scale and it is possible that the large number of blobs is causing the garbage collecting component to take a long time and consume CPU. We will look at improving the efficiency of the garbage collector in the future. In the meantime, reducing the number of blobs stored in the emulator should improve this.

Comment: I managed to profile the emulator process and saw a high number of "garbage collection" calls. This is also visible in the detailed logs, once logging is enabled. Given that real Azure storage is pretty cheap I decided to move to "the real thing" even for individual development environments.

Comment: After 2 years the emulator v4.3 still consumer a lot of CPU when just idling and has literally 1 table, 5 queues and 0 records/messages..

Comment: Coming up on 4 years.  Still getting this with v5.3.  Barely any blobs defined and it happens while sitting idle.

Comment: Also seeing high cpu when not using any blobs.  Single table, single queue

Comment: The emulator is useless in its current form. Surely, the makers of this don't dogfood their product.

Comment: Almost 2021 still seeing this issue